# Error when using typdef template in another template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have a little problem with templates. Since it's easier to explain with code, here is my problem.

I have an interface class :

```
template <typename T>
class IElemValidator
{
public:
    virtual bool validate(T val) const = 0 ;
    virtual ~IElemValidator(){};
};
```

and a typedef struct :

```
template <typename T>
struct vecValidators
{
    typedef boost::ptr_vector<IElemValidator<T>> Type;
};
```

I can use my typedef struct everywhere except in the parameters of another template classe like this :

```
template <typename T>
class CTestMaybe
{
public:
    CTestMaybe(vecValidators<T>::Type* a_Validators);
};
```

When trying to compile, I have this error:

```
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Type'
```

Of course, I can do this :

```
template <typename T>
class CTestMaybe
{
private:
    typedef boost::ptr_vector<IElemValidator<T>> vecValidator;

public:
    CTestMaybe(vecValidator* a_Validators);


};
```

and it's working well but I'm kinda loosing the interest of my struct class.

So, what I'm doing wrong ? Is there a "correct" way to do what I want ?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `typename`:

```
template <typename T>
class CTestMaybe
{
public:
    CTestMaybe(typename vecValidators<T>::Type* a_Validators);
};
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I knew there was something with typename but I couldn't find where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

The type `vecValidators<T>::Type` is a *dependent name* (if I get the terminology right). This means you have to put an extra `typename` there:

```
CTestMaybe(typename vecValidators<T>::Type* a_Validators);
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ compiler a type in your function declaration, but instead it see `vecValidators<T>::Type*` and since `vecValidators` is a `template` it don't know that `Type` is a type inside of it, so you must say it to the compiler using `typename` so you should change your function to:

```
CTestMaybe(typename vecValidators<T>::Type* a_Validators);
```